# bilateral filter parameters

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you know what do these two parameters mean in bilateral filter? SigmaSpatial & SigmaRange

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62484/bilateral-filter-parameters/) by [ati](https://answers.ros.org/users/4842/ati/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-05-11**:
If you found the answer helpful, please accept it so the question can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Let me google that for you!](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bilateral+filter+parameter)

Long explanation: http://people.csail.mit.edu/sparis/publi/2009/fntcgv/Paris_09_Bilateral_filtering.pdf

Short explanation (taken from [PCL documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_bilateral_filter.html)):

- *sigma_s* the half size of the Gaussian bilateral filter window to use
- *sigma_r* the new standard deviation parameter
- For more information please see C. Tomasi and R. Manduchi. Bilateral Filtering for Gray and Color Images. In Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Computer Vision, 1998.

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1